# MySQL update with INSERT

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, sql-update

I am using PHP, MySQL and CodeIgniter. I have a `product` table and `product_item` table.

`product` table contains the info of main *Product* and `product_item` contains the info of materials that used to make *Product*.

On editing of *Product*, I also need to update the `product_item` table.

Example: I added one more item to the table, so I need to `INSERT` the value to the table.

I got two ideas:

1. Just get the values from the form, if item already exists `UPDATE` it, otherwise `INSERT` with looping through the items.
2. [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

There may be many ways, but what is the most effective/good practice to perform this? Usually I have about 1-10 rows to be considered.

Answer (score 0):

REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted.